# How to get data from mongoDB on the basis of a value inside a nested object

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Below is my API for fetching all the orders of a specific restaurant from a mongoDB database.
My search is based on the restaurant id which I am getting from params and passing it to the query object.
query1 is working but query2 does not return my data.
It is returning an empty array. If I pass a simple object in find() then I am getting a response. But when i use a nested object for getting data I get nothing.

```
exports.getOrders = async (req, res) => {
  const restId = req.params.restId;
  console.log("restaurant id", restId);
  if (!restId) return res.status(404).send("No restaurant ID found in params");

  const query1 = {grandTotal: 600};
  const query2 = { restaurant: { restaurantId: restId } };
  const response = await Orders.find(query2);
  console.log("Printing response inside API function", response);
}
```

Below is my MongoDB Schema of Orders.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const orderSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  customer: {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    contact: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    customerId: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Customer",
      required: true,
    },
    customerAddress: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  restaurant: {
    restaurantName: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    contact: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    restaurantId: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Restaurant",
      required: true,
    },
  },
  /*date: {
    day: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    },
    month: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    year: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  type: {
    type: String,
    enum: ["delivery","takeaway"],
    required: true,
  },*/
  items: [
     {
      itemId: { type: String, required: true },   
      itemName: { type: String, required: true },
      itemDescription: { type: String, required: true },
      price: {type: Number, required: true},
      quantity: { type: Number, required: true },
      total: {type: Number, required: true},
    },
  ],

  grandTotal: {type: Number, required: true},
  status: {
    type: String,
    enum: ["pending", "rejected","cancelled","accepted","received"],
    required: true,
  },

});

orderSchema.virtual("booking", {
  ref: "Booking",
  localField: "_id",
  foreignField: "orderId",
});

orderSchema.set("toObject", { virtual: true });
orderSchema.set("toJSON", { virtual: true });

const Orders = mongoose.model("Orders", orderSchema);

exports.Orders = Orders;
```

Comment: use this `{"restaurant.restaurantId":restId}` instead of `{restaurant: { restaurantId :restId } } `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change query2 to this

```
  const query2 = { "restaurant.restaurantId": restId } };
```